# How to select UITableView cell programmatically (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UITableViewController` and I need to select and scroll to one of the cells when the view loads. The reason I need the cell selected rather than just making it look selected (with an accessory or whatever) is that I want it to have a different background and no separators above/below (which is what happens when a table cell is selected), and I want the cell initially visible (if it's too far down).

I've read the two other answers and they don't work or I don't understand them. I'm not sure where I should put the `self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath` and `self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath`. I tried putting it in `viewDidLoad()` and it had no effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use `viewDidAppear`

```
func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(myPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
}
```

Comment: Just a few errors (in case someone just copies this) bool should be `Bool` and myPath should be just path, otherwise it works. And for me it works better in `viewWillAppear()` because there's a delay when used in `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: let path = NSIndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
mySelfDelegatedTable.selectRow(at: path as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle) //worked for me

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let path = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: path, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the selectRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView in your view controller's viewDidAppear method

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // replace forRow: value with the index of the cell
    // replace inSection: value with the section the cell is in
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Middle)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given solutions didn't work for me. So, here is the solution for swift 5

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //Choose the row and section
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
    tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
}
```