# Table view cell is remain unselected in editing mood

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want even numbered rows of tableview to be selected when table is first loaded. I have set the tableview  editing style to "Multiple Selection During Editing" from storyboard. I have tried two ways to do this, first approach is like below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        cell?.isSelected = true
    }else {
        cell?.isSelected = false
    }
    return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return data.count
}
```

but it does not make the row selected. table looks like

[image]

second way i tried is to call  `self.tableView.selectRow(at: index path, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)` whith removing additional logic in cellForRow method used in first approach. this approach seems to work.

Can anyone tell me why first approach is not working and weather my second approach is appropriate or not. Thanks :)

Comment: cell?.isSelected = true but you are not making that RadioButton Image Highlight when selected

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411249/how-do-you-select-uitableview-rows-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158353/how-to-select-uitableview-cell-programmatically-swift-2/36158531

Comment: Just a comment on style: If you write `cell?.isSelected = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)` (instead of the `if`-condition) you get less code and it is much better readable ;)

Comment: Try to use a default UITableViewCell for a test. Does it works fine with the default one?

Comment: @Michael , I appreciate what you suggested.

Comment: @iOS I can make row selected by calling "selectRow()" for the row i want to be selected. but my question was why "cell.isSlected" is not working.

Comment: @iOSGeek, what do you mean by highlighting radio button? I did not use any image .

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are doing deselectRowAtIndexPath in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.